# How find Row Number of Value within Array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I've saved all my data to an array, and I want to get the 'name' of a supplied 'code'.

How to I get the array row of that code?

Also, is this the most efficient process?

```
 id  |  code  |  name     |  
__________________________
1   |  KNTY  |  Kentucky |
2   |  PURD  |  Purdue   |
3   |  TEXS  |  Texas    |


// Move data to array
$search = "SELECT * FROM table";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $search);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

// Code I want a name for
$code = "KNTY";
// MYSTERY STEP I NEED HELP WITH
$name = $array[$id]['name'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit with the hint of the comment of [itachi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091131/find-row-number-of-value-within-array/29091156?noredirect=1#comment46414589_29091156). You can use the `code` as the key of the `$array`:

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM table";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $search);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $array[$row['code']] = $row['name'];
}

// Code I want a name for
$code = "KNTY";

$name = $array[$code];
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian - I'll be running this query a lot. I'd prefer not run multiple queries but rather get this information from the array.

Comment: Yes, I want to SELECT * from table only once and save to array. Then I want to manipulate the data within the array.

Comment: in the loop, use `$array[$row['name']][] = $row;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do something like that, while inside the fetch loop, assign the `code` as key. This must be unique though:

```
$search = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $search);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // assign `$row['code']` as key to this rowset
    $array[$row['code']] = $row;
}

$code = 'KNTY';
if(isset($array[$code])) { // add some checking, you wouldn't want undefined index errors
    $name = $array[$code]['name'];
    echo $name;
} else {
    echo 'Sorry not found';
}
```